# Excel | How to create multi level (not multi-tier) pivots

Tags: excel, pivot

Is it possible, in Excel, to create a pivot that essentially shows multiple views at the same time.  In the example below, we have three views of Company Sales, by Location, by Category and by Retail/Trade.
Is this possible, I've done it manually, but it would be great if it was possible to it automatically as there are upto four tiers in each view.

SALES:

### UK | 4.5M

- Hampshire | 1M
- Berkshire | 1.5M
- Gloucester | 2M

---

- Software | 2.5M
- Hardware | 2M

---

- Retail | 3.5M
- Trade | 1M

Comment: Do you have Power Pivot?

Comment: I do have Power Pivot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your data looks like, but starting from a basic set of data and loading it up into a Power Pivot Data Table that's dedicated to your pivot table you can get close.

[image]

Create a Power Query (Connection Only) for each grouping that you want. Keep the column for the group, and add a new column for the group name:

[image]

Do the same for each group, and in the final Power Query 'Append' the previous Power Queries and Load To The Data Model:

[image]

You now have a table in your data model that has the data prepared for your pivot table:

[image]

This new table is semi-additive and so the total Sum for the whole table is wrong, but the numbers at each level/group are correct.

Comment: Interesting, like the way your thinking. Will take a look, thanks.